# Xpath: select class that contains sub-element span with some text?

Tags: xpath

As per related question answered I tried,

```
.//*[contains(@class, 'info') and contains(., 'someText')]
```

but I get the error invalid xpath.

How can I get this class or the span element from this ?

```
<p class="info">  <-- I want to select this class 
<span> someText</span>  <-- that contains span with this text
</p>
```

Comment: That XPath isn't invalid and should pretty much work the way you want it to. What are you using to evaluate it?

Comment: XPath is correct. Can you share full stacktrace?

Comment: I am using chrome developer tools and the error I get is as: 
`Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute '$x' on 'CommandLineAPI': The string './/*[contains(@class, 'info') and ./span[contains(., 'SomeText')]]' is not a valid XPath expression.
    at <anonymous>:1:1`

Answer (score 0):

**`xpath`** expression:

```
//*[contains(@class, 'info') and ./span[contains(., 'someText')]]
```